# Interaction between C++ and Rails applications

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, interaction

I have two applications: c++ service and a RoR web server (they are both running at same VPS)

I need to "send" some variables (and then do something with them) from each other. For exaple, i'm looking for something like this:

```
// my C++ sample
void SendMessage(string message) {
   SendTo("127.0.0.1", message);
}

void GetMessage(string message) {
   if (message == "stop")
      SendMessage("success");
}

# Ruby sample
# application_controller.rb

def stop
   @m = Messager.new
   @m.send("stop")
end
```

I have never used it before, and i even don't know which technology should i search and learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i have found the solution. Its TCP sockets:

Ruby TCP server, to send messages:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {                       
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime)
    client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
    client.close               
  end

}
```

Ruby client, to accept messages:

```
require 'socket'

host = 'localhost'
port = 2001 # it should be running server, or it will be connection error

s = TCPSocket.open(host, port)
  while line = s.gets
    puts line.chop
  end
s.close
```

Now you should write TCP-server+client in another application. But you have got the idea.